# HTML drop down not dropping down .. Why

Tags: html, css

First I am using Chrome ... If you look at this [First jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/marmantrout/ws0sf7tf/3/) the drop down will not drop down.

`<div id="column1" style="float: left; width: 400px;">`

If I change the width from 400 to 900 then it will work fine see this [Second jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/marmantrout/28o0e5jp/1/).

`<div id="column1" style="float: left; width: 900px;">`

I don't understand why CSS and HTML does this to me. So I am looking for a explanation of why.

Comment: "I don't understand why CSS and HTML does this to me" - :) :) :) ROTFLMAO

Comment: you  fiddle working what is the issue ?

Comment: I am looking at the HTML and it seems overly complicated - what are you trying to achieve? can it be simplified?

Comment: @Naila it does not work if you change the width to `400px` as described in the problem (see first fiddle)

Comment: @ochi i didn't see anything

Comment: html is from a bigger Solution I have simplified it extreemely

Comment: @Naila interesting - which browser are you using? I can see it using Chrome (on Win7)

Comment: Chrome is my browser of choice

Comment: i am using firefox , let me check with chrome

Comment: Please consider including a [mcve] to your question. Links can be unavailable at any given time making the question incomplete and thus, impossible to answer

Comment: Just because you don't have the answer does not make it impossible to answer ;)

Comment: If the question is incomplete (i.e. no one can the the original HTML/JS) I am pretty sure it will be nearly impossible to answer (I guess only by guessing)

Comment: seriously if I showed you the original HTML/JS you would complain more about it not being minimal. You can see the problem by comparing the two fiddles. No need to get upset about it

Comment: Oh, I am not upset, (I am sorry I gave you that impression) - I am just saying that, it's good practice to include a [mcve] to the question to make it self-sufficient.  I am not asking for all the original HTML/JS - only the code from the fiddle should be enough

Comment: btw, it is definitely related to  `column-count: 3;   column-gap: 10px;` - if you remove those from `.topColorTile`, the drop down works... I am now investigating why that is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `column-count` you use makes the content of the div to be divided into 3 columns, and that division cause the "extra" content to be "displayed" outside your container (which is only `375px` wide).

The reason for the `900px` (of the container) to fix this is that it gives enough space for the `<select>` element to render (btw - `800px` is enough).

Comment: Why does the select element need 800 more px to render ?

Comment: The width of your `select` is ~120px, you set the content to be divided to 3 columns, it would be 360px for that, add the 375px of the container and (probably) other padding/margin/border, you should get to something near that number. IMHO it looks like a bug in chrome. I don't see a good reason for the browser to behave like this.

Comment: I never thought about it being a chrome bug but this used to work and I have gone back to the original commit and it doesn't even work

Comment: @MicahArmantrout will appreciate a vote on the answer (and accept if you believe it's the right one). Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry the goal was to answer when I got back to work

Answer (score 1):

You have this css rule in class .topColorTile

```
column-count: 3;
column-gap: 10px;
```

If you set width of #column1 by 400px, class .topColorTile will be inherited.
And you also set width of .topColorTile div.topColorCard by 375px, it's wrong here, you can not set with of child node larger than width of parent/column-count.

Sorry for my bad english :D

Answer (score 1):

As others have answered, you have this CSS rule on `.topColorTile`

```
column-count: 3;
column-gap: 10px;
```

but also have this rule on `div.topColorCard`

```
 width: 375px;
```

When the parent container is only `400px` the div gets broken down into 3 columns.  Since there are no other divs (or elements) inside, the card containing the select uses the entire width (`375px` as specified in the CSS) with the remaining two columns added next to them but with no content (i.e. invisible)

This makes the select statement to fully show but the overlapping (and invisible) 'columns' prevent the click event to trigger the dropdown action.

Changing the number of columns to 1 would solve the issue (or removing the CSS rule, in this case would be the same)

Setting the width of `.topColorCard` to a smaller amount (that would fit the parent's 400px) would also do it (i.e. `130px x 3 < 400px`)

Making the parent's width to a higher number (like `900px`) would also prevent this overlapping.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div style="display:inline; float:right;">
```

That's why... `float:right`

Change it to `float:left` or adjust width of div's

You have a big mess in your code. Check FreeCodeCamp online tutorial to improve your skills.

Comment: Thanks its messy for a reason but i digress ... but I need it to float right and it doesn't really answer my question of WHY

Comment: The question was not "how to fix" but "what is the cause".

Comment: Why? You have duplicated divs with the same class names, anonymus div's with inline styles, and divs covers each other. Clean up the code!

Comment: I already asked the question, it's not OP's code - it's what it is for now